# I can't get a second router to extend my network over powerline adapters

Tags: networking, router, adapter, powerline-networking

I have a main router Netgear DGN2200 then I have a cable from the LAN to a Belkin powerline adapter. Up in my loft I have the other powerline adapter connected (via LAN) to a second router, a Netgear wnr2200. I have it all connected correct with the dhcp turned off on the second router etc.

Heres the problem. The second router doesn't work over the powerline adapters. When the two routers are connected direct via one ethernet cable the second router works fine with the exact same settings. I don't get it.

Anyone else had this problem?

Thanks

Comment: While your question is interesting, it might be more suited to SuperUser, here we deal with business type questions and hardware.

Comment: Since you've said "loft" I'm going to assume you're british.  Are these two Powerline devices on different ring-mains? Which would mean there's circuit breakers between them? .. I've seen circuit breakers interfering with Powerline hardware, as they work by having some inductors on the line, which can cause untold mischief with the frequency that Powerline adaptors operate at.

Comment: Sorry NickW. Thanks @Tom O'Connor that sounds like it might be the problem. I'll try it on the same ring. They work fine if I plug the second cable straight into my computer rather than the 2nd router. Will just have to get a switch instead.

Comment: I've abandoned Powerline at home numerous times, because it's very dependent on pretty perfect cabling between the adapters.  Something that's very difficult in both modern (because of inductive breakers) and old houses (because of old wiring).  ISTR that american houses are wired fundamentally differently, but IANAElectrician.

Comment: @TomO'Connor It's annoying that it's not working. Glad I didn't buy them and just borrowed them. It's annoying also because the second router works up there if I connect the cable into the WAN and have it as a separate network.

Comment: Please check the powerline LEDs on the two powerline adapters. I'ld guess they do not see each other, so there is no network connection between the two routers

Comment: I have Netgear adapters similar to these... one thing worth noting is that they have a distance limitation, or at least mine do. The adapters could only be 1000 feet apart of cabling throughout the house otherwise they wouldn't connect to eachother... so maybe yours are to far apart from one another?

Comment: @C-dizzle Thanks. They are definitely connected to each other as they work when I plug it straight into my mac. Also the router works when I use it on another subnet. It's just when I disable dhcp and use it as an AP that it doesn't want to get the IPs from the first router. Like the powerline adapters are it letting DHCP work.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have already identified the problem. *The powerline adapter*

Powerline adapter's are notorious for being unreliable and flakey. Searching google for "powerline adapter problem" returns over a quarter of a million hits.

Netgear has a troubleshooting guide that I'll [link here](http://forum1.netgear.com/showthread.php?t=18694)

If absolutly can not run a cat 5 cable, as a last ditch effort try moving your router to a different subnet. I've seen many inexpensive SOHO devices that can't handle classless routing.

(Move from 192.168.0.x to 192.168.1.x)